# run ai models inference on client devices

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am working with client devices that are not connected to the internet or any network servers
these client devices are supposed to run inferences on a pytorch model
what is the best way to setup these client machines in a way that the user cannot have access to the pytorch models

Note: the user must have access to the client device but we want to hide the models so they cannot be used outside this particular device

Sorry if any thing I wrote is not clear

Thanks

Comment: Can you download it from a web service and encrypt it or something to that effect?

Comment: during setup time I can setup everything and ship the client device to the client and everything is functioning. what I am concerned about is that the client will be able to get the pytorch model and replicate the solution we are providing. so I am looking for a method to keep the pytorch model on the machine without the user being able to get the pytorch model and using it anywhere else